# Why does this simple code with printf "freeze"?

Tags: c

When I run this code the program freezes,why?

```
main()
{
int co;
    co=0;
    while (co<10) {

        co=co+1;

        if (co==3)
            printf("The number is now three.");
        if (co==7)
            printf("The number is now seven.");
        else
            printf(co);

}
}
```

I'm compiling it with mingw GCC.

Comment: At least you could add a \n at the end of the strings.

Comment: What book are you learning from?

Comment: And also: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find an answer helpful, you can vote it up! If you feel that someone has adequately answered your question, click the check-mark next to the answer to accept it.

Comment: Im learning from a pdf book called ctutor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't print `co` like that:

You need to do it like this:

```
printf("%d",co);
```

`printf` takes as a first parameter, a string with format specifiers. The latter (optional) parameters are the arguments themselves.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Here's a more cleaned version of your code:

```
int main(){

    int co = 0;
    while (co < 10) {

        co = co + 1;

        if (co == 3)
            printf("The number is now three.");
        if (co == 7)
            printf("The number is now seven.");
        else
            printf("%d\n",co);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition, GCC likely issues a warning (or several), and OP should *not* ignore any warnings.

Answer (score 4):

You musn't call `printf(co)`. `printf()` expects a formant string + some optional arguments:

```
printf("%d\n", co);
```

(additionally you ought to explicitly specify `int` as the return type for `main()` in every C program written after 1989 and provide a `return` value within `main` too)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to compile with **warnings enabled**. Then you would see directly what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have stated, you need to print it using a format string (the percentages thing). For integers, you can use %i or %d in the format string.

```
printf("%d", co);
```

If you wanted to print something a bit more complex, you could do this.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
printf("%d+%d=%d", a, b, (a+b));
```

The printf function takes a variable number of parameters, so you can pass as many strings, ints or whatever, into the function call.

Additionally, I would recommend changing co=co+1; in your code to this.

```
++co;
```

Put simply, this increments the co variable. You could use co++ too, but it just depends on your personal preference.

Comment: But this is C not C++, so how can you increment myObject if you don't have classes and can't overload the ++ operator?

Comment: Fair point. I guess I should read the tags more thoroughly. Edited.

Comment: so there is no `++` operator in C ?

Comment: That's not what we said. The ++ operator and similar operators such as --, +, -, *, /, etc are only available to the built-in types in C, and not to structs. For example, you couldn't create a struct called MyStruct and do myStructVar+myStructVar2. It's not possible in C.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a couple of things and show you another way of writing your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int co;

   for (co = 0; co < 10; co++) {
      if (co == 3)
         printf("The number is now three.\n");
      else if (co == 7)
         printf("The number is now seven.\n");
      else
         printf("%d\n", co);

   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The way you have an initial value for *co*, a condition and an instruction to modify it (increment), makes it well suited to use a **for** statement, as you can neatly have those three parts in the one line.

Also, I think you'd want the `if (co == 7)` to be `else if (co == 7)`, so that when you get to the number 3, you don't print *"The number is now three."* and also the number 3.

And obviously the main answer to your question, which I know has already been answered, is that *printf* was treating the value of *co* as an address of the start of a string, since the first argument to *printf* is the format **string**.